# php image compression gif without loss animated

Tags: php

1. php image compression gif without loss animated
2. gif without loss animated
3. Which is the best PHP method to reduce the image size without losing quality

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      
   <form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     <input type='file' name='imagefile' >
     <input type='submit' value='Upload' name='upload'> 
   </form>

   <?
   if(isset($_POST['upload'])){


     $filename = $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];
    

     $valid_ext = array('png','jpeg','jpg','gif');


     $location = "images/".$filename;


     $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);


     if(in_array($file_extension,$valid_ext)){


       compressImage($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'],$location,60);

     }else{
       echo "Invalid file type.";
     }
   }

   // Compress image
   function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {

     $info = getimagesize($source);

     if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
       $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

     elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
       $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

     elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
       $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

     imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

   }

   ?>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

thod to reduce the image size without losing quality [closed]*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   
<form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input type='file' name='imagefile' >
  <input type='submit' value='Upload' name='upload'> 
</form>

<?
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){


  $filename = $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];
 

  $valid_ext = array('png','jpeg','jpg','gif');


  $location = "images/".$filename;


  $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);


  if(in_array($file_extension,$valid_ext)){


    compressImage($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'],$location,60);

  }else{
    echo "Invalid file type.";
  }
}

// Compress image
function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {

  $info = getimagesize($source);

  if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

  elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

  elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

  imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its unclear, what you are trying to achieve. ? please elaborate the description

Comment: check agin my code

Comment: image compressor in php to loss my file animation

Comment: http://www.superphoto.org/uploads/5/7/8/1/5781742/spiral-loop_1_orig.gif

Comment: Hi, let me get more clear, and confirm me if that going to work then i can post solution.
GIF is basically set of images in given time duration.
So if you are directly trying to compress it, it will do with first image only thus you loose animation. Solution should be, spread GIF into multiple images, perform compression on each, and re-create GIF with same timeframe.
If you think will work, i can post solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating image from gif. that why its loosing its animation. because gifs are set of images altogether, compressing them into image will only keep the first image of that set.

If you want to keep the quality and compress it go for jpeg. Read this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/283366/reducing-an-image-size-without-losing-its-quality) regarding image size reduction and after deciding on the technique, use [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

and finally try this one to compress gif image by keeping its animation. however gif images are tend to lose quality when you compress them.

```
imagetruecolortopalette($img, false, 16);  //  compress to 16 colors in gif palette (change 16 to anything between 1-256)
```

Comment: I try but not working
$image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    imagetruecolortopalette($image, false, 16);  //  compress to 16 colors in gif palette (change 16 to anything between 1-256)
    imagegif($image, $destination);  //  $destination_filename is the location on your server where you want to save the